# How to show Images calling from Database with PHP only one time

Tags: php, mysql

When I call images from the database random, it loads them x times, but I want to show them only once.

```
$random = array_rand(Database::query('SELECT * FROM ADVERTISEMENTS' ));
$adv_sql = "SELECT * FROM `ADVERTISEMENTS` WHERE `id` = $random ";

$advResult = Database::single($adv_sql, $random['id']);
$advExplode = explode('/', $advResult['upload']);
$advLocation = 'url/location' . end($advExplode);
```

Comment: Most probably depends on how you have implemented your Database adapter

Comment: Do you mean that you want to select ONE random image from the table?

Comment: you have to store allready loaded images - ex. with sessions

Comment: I have like 10 images, And they are being loaded all 10 of them now, but for example: image1 is being loaded 30 times in my page and image2 20times, I want all pictures to shown only 1 time in a page.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand your abstraction.

Your second query has condition `id = $random`, but you bind params in your `single()` method: `$adv_sql, $random['id']`.

We don't know your methods work, you should have shown us their implementation.

Anyway, isn't one query better for this?

```
SELECT * FROM `ADVERTISEMENTS` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Or without `LIMIT` if you want to recieve all

If you don't want to show an already loaded image in the second request, you'd need to log which images where shown so far, into a database, cookies or sessions, depending on the needs.

---

Or, bind the shown images to an instance.

This is my test so far:

```
class Images {

    private $_imagesShown = array("''");

    private function getShownImages() {
        return implode(',', $this->_imagesShown);
    }

    private function setShownImage($row) {
        $this->_imagesShown[] = $row['id'];
    }

    public function getImages() {
        $query = "SELECT id, image FROM images WHERE id NOT IN ({$this->getShownImages()})";
        $result = mysqli_query($query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $this->setShownImage($row);
        return $row;
    }
}

$img = new Images();
var_dump($img->getImages());
var_dump($img->getImages());
var_dump($img->getImages());
var_dump($img->getImages());
var_dump($img->getImages());
var_dump($img->getImages());
var_dump($img->getImages());
var_dump($img->getImages());
```

Outputs:

```
array (size=2)
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'img' => string '0.jpg' (length=1)

array (size=2)
  'id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'img' => string '1.jpg' (length=1)

array (size=2)
  'id' => string '3' (length=1)
  'img' => string '2.jpg' (length=1)

array (size=2)
  'id' => string '4' (length=1)
  'img' => string '3.jpg' (length=1)

array (size=2)
  'id' => string '5' (length=1)
  'img' => string '4.jpg' (length=1)

array (size=2)
  'id' => string '6' (length=1)
  'img' => string '12.jpg' (length=1)

array (size=2)
  'id' => string '7' (length=1)
  'img' => string '55.jpg' (length=1)
```

so each call of `getImages()` returns a non shown image

Comment: I have like 10 images, And they are being loaded all 10 of them now, but for example: image1 is being loaded 30 times in my page and image2 20times, I want all pictures to shown only 1 time in a page.